# Correct way to return a property as a specific type from a union type

Tags: angular, typescript, types, casting

I have 1 property I need to return from a function in different places in an application.
This property could be 1 of 2 types, both have properties that are string literals. One is an extension of the other.
How can I return the same variable I am passing in cast as one type or the other in a type guard?

```
type NameA = 'A'| 'B' | 'C'
type NameB = NameA | 'D' | 'E'
```

```
function nameTypeGuard(
    name: NameA | NameB
  ):  NameA | NameB{
    if (some condition) {
      return name as NameA;
    } else {
      return name as NameB;
    }
  }
```

Comment: both of the names have 'A' in them. isn't that a bug?

Comment: There is an overlap of properties. I will amend my question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) as the return type. Using Generics, my initial solution would look something like this:

```js
type NameA = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
type NameB = 'A' | 'D' | 'E';

function nameTypeGuard<
  T extends NameA | NameB,
  R = T extends NameA ? NameA : NameB
>(
  name: T
): R {
  return name as unknown as R;
}

const a = nameTypeGuard("A");
const b = nameTypeGuard("B");
const c = nameTypeGuard("C");
const d = nameTypeGuard("D");
const e = nameTypeGuard("E");
```

TypeScript Playground: [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgWwgQSgXigcmZqAfLAIVwMwGFMAoUSWRCQ9LHfLAERKwFErKAzAK4A7AMbAAlgHshUIfQAq4CAHEBcAE4ATADyUoUeVAgAPYBCGaAznSSoC8JIQA0eqACUmhk2YvWHKKAB%20GwCALhDCSgA%20AApXOSRw%20UoASnCPAG9XdQhgAXUZBOg4a2EAayFJAHcZEvcAbkoAX0pKEWlLYCg4JiLFSFUNTRiAImQRlMb2oU6oACNehSVBrVHCCamOrpFFpH6VNVWRsg22rahNXYh9leGRtlPp2egMPuXDu65ToA)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what condition would you use to check if the property was one type or the other before returning the cast value?

Comment: @OHello As types are only relevant at compile time (not at runtime, because TypeScript compiles down to JavaScript, which is not strongly typed, and the TypeScript compiler strips the types from the source), the type decision is performed solely by the type system (by the second generic argument (R)) without the need for a runtime check.